# flask app engine does not work with firestore?

Tags: google-app-engine, flask, google-app-engine-python, google-cloud-firestore

Setup: Run in Google Cloud Shell Standard Env

I tried to access firestore from the flask app using `from google.cloud import firestore`

I have installed it using `pip install --upgrade google-cloud-firestore -t lib`. If I run the script manually, it works fine. But when using `dev_appserver.py`, it fails. Got the error below.

```
$ dev_appserver.py app.yaml
INFO     2017-10-06 07:34:35,301 devappserver2.py:105] Skipping SDK update check.
INFO     2017-10-06 07:34:35,391 api_server.py:300] Starting API server at: http://0.0.0.0:34796
WARNING  2017-10-06 07:34:35,391 dispatcher.py:312] Your python27 micro version is below 2.7.12, our current production version.
INFO     2017-10-06 07:34:35,440 dispatcher.py:251] Starting module "default" running at: http://0.0.0.0:8080
INFO     2017-10-06 07:34:35,441 admin_server.py:116] Starting admin server at: http://0.0.0.0:8000

ERROR    2017-10-06 07:34:42,266 wsgi.py:263]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/google/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 240, in Handle
    handler = _config_handle.add_wsgi_middleware(self._LoadHandler())
  File "/google/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 299, in _LoadHandler
    handler, path, err = LoadObject(self._handler)
  File "/google/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 85, in LoadObject
    obj = __import__(path[0])
  File "/home/user1/projects/probfe/main.py", line 10, in <module>
    from google.cloud import firestore
  File "/google/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/python/runtime/sandbox.py", line 1132, in load_module
    raise ImportError('No module named %s' % fullname)
ImportError: No module named google.gax
```

However, in my `lib`, I can see them.

```
$ls lib
builtins                       future-0.16.0.dist-info                         itsdangerous.pyc                requests-2.18.4.dist-info
cachetools                     futures-3.1.1.dist-info                         jinja2                          rsa
cachetools-2.0.1.dist-info     google                                          Jinja2-2.9.6.dist-info          rsa-3.4.2.dist-info
certifi                        googleapis_common_protos-1.5.3.dist-info        libfuturize                     setuptools
certifi-2017.7.27.1.dist-info  googleapis_common_protos-1.5.3-py2.7-nspkg.pth  libpasteurize                   setuptools-36.5.0.dist-info
chardet                        google_auth-1.1.1.dist-info                     _markupbase                     six-1.11.0.dist-info
chardet-3.0.4.dist-info        google_auth-1.1.1-py2.7-nspkg.pth               markupsafe                      six.py
click                          google_cloud_core-0.27.1.dist-info              MarkupSafe-1.0.dist-info        six.pyc
click-6.7.dist-info            google_cloud_core-0.27.1-py3.6-nspkg.pth        past                            socketserver
concurrent                     google_cloud_firestore-0.27.0.dist-info         pkg_resources                   tests
copyreg                        google_cloud_firestore-0.27.0-py3.6-nspkg.pth   ply                             _thread
dill                           google_gax-0.15.15.dist-info                    ply-3.8.dist-info               tkinter
dill-0.2.7.1.dist-info         google_gax-0.15.15-py2.7-nspkg.pth              protobuf-3.4.0.dist-info        urllib3
_dummy_thread                  grpc                                            protobuf-3.4.0-py2.7-nspkg.pth  urllib3-1.22.dist-info
easy_install.py                grpcio-1.4.0.dist-info                          pyasn1                          werkzeug
easy_install.pyc               html                                            pyasn1-0.3.7.dist-info          Werkzeug-0.12.2.dist-info
enum                           http                                            pyasn1_modules                  winreg
enum34-1.1.6.dist-info         idna                                            pyasn1_modules-0.1.4.dist-info  xmlrpc
flask                          idna-2.6.dist-info                              queue
Flask-0.12.2.dist-info         itsdangerous-0.24.dist-info                     reprlib
future                         itsdangerous.py                                 requests
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using `dev_appserver.py` it means you have a standard env application. And in the standard env all external dependencies need to be installed *in your app*, not on the local python instalation (which is what you did with your `pip` invocation).

From [Installing a third-party library](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/tools/using-libraries-python-27#installing_a_third-party_library):

> 1. Create a directory to store your third-party libraries, such as `lib/`.
>
>    ```
>    mkdir lib
>    ```
> 2. Use [pip](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pip) (version 6 or later) with the `-t <directory>` flag to copy the libraries into the folder you created in the previous
>      step. For example:
>
>    ```
>    pip install -t lib/ <library_name>
>    ```

Comment: I had done that and got the error. In my requirements.txt, it includes `Flask==0.12.2` and `google-cloud-firestore` . I forgot to add that in my original post. I just edited that in the original post.

Comment: You didn't mention how you use that `requirements.txt` - it's not used automatically in the standard env...

Comment: here is what I did: `pip install --upgrade -r requirements.txt -t lib`. Then I ran: `dev_appserver.py app.yaml` . Did I miss anything? I just used [this flask app engine guide](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/getting-started/python-standard-env) and add `google-cloud-firestore` in the requirements.txt

Comment: OK, at least now it complains about `google.gax`, not `google.cloud.firestore` - so the original problem is fixed. Check if it's indeed missing in your `lib` dir. If it is try adding `google-gax` explicitly to your `requirements.txt`, then retry.

Comment: `google-gax` is in my `lib`. I attached my `lib` in the original post. I also tried to add `google-gax` explicitly to `requirements.txt`. I got the same error. I ran everything in Google Cloud Shell (if that makes a difference)